# Jsoup - Problem selecting a tag

Tags: java, jsoup

Is there a way to select an element following another one?

For example if I have :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

and I want to select the first th I can do :

```
Elements select = Jsoup.parse(HTML_PAGE).select("th");
Element element = select.get(0);
```

But how can I do to say : select the td that follow the first th?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an combine different [JSoup Selectors](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html).

For instance, for your question: "select the td that follow the first th"

- lt pseudo selector:

  - `:lt(n)` - elements whose sibling index is less than n
- Sibling selector: you have two options:

  - `E + F` - an F element immediately preceded by sibling E
  - `E ~ F` -  an F element preceded by sibling E

So, for selecting the first th it would be `th:lt(1)`, and for the td that follows it `+ td`.

The final code:

```
Elements select = Jsoup.parse(HTML_PAGE).select("th:lt(1) + td");
Element element = select.get(0);
```

The element returned will be the td tag immediately preceded by the first th tag found.