# Jsoup - :lt() select does not work

Tags: css-selectors, jsoup

In my html code, there are 120 li's like this therefore I want to limit instead of getting all results so I write

```
doc.select(".productContainer:lt(50) .productName")
```

In addition I have check this question also. I tried it but it doesnt work. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12317514/621951)

HTML is:

```
<li>
<div class="productContainer">
    <div class="productPic">
        <a>
            <img src="..." alt="..." ></a>
    </div>
    <div class="productName">
        <a href=".." title="...">
            abc
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="productPrice">
        <span id="...">...</span>
    </div>
</div>
</li>

 <li>
<div class="productContainer">
    <div class="productPic">
        <a>
            <img src="..." alt="..." ></a>
    </div>
    <div class="productName">
        <a href=".." title="...">
            abc
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="productPrice">
        <span id="...">...</span>
    </div>
</div>
 </li>
```

Thanks...

Comment: I have also checked this link and tried it. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4083803/621951

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select query is wrong, look at my solution - query for reading product names from list:

```
doc.select("li:lt(50) > div.productContainer > div.productName").text();
```

This works for me!

Comment: I think div.productContainer is only one in tree under li.